# Android Auto desktop-head-unit.exe fails to start on Windows

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-auto

When I attempt to run desktop-head-unit.exe in Windows from the command prompt nothing happens.  The program seems to return with no error messages and no emulator being started.  Are there other extras that I need to download to get this to run?

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html#running-dhu?

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh when I get to step #7 in that tutorial, the desktop-head-unit.exe immediately returns and nothing happens.  No DHU emulator screen appears.  So far I have opened the SDK Manager and downloaded every optional Tool and Extra before rebooting my Windows box.  But still no success running the DHU.

Comment: As a quick sanity check, can anybody actually run desktop-head-unit.exe on Windows?  Maybe my machine is just messed up.

Comment: I was able to get the DHU to run on Windows 8 but not Windows 7.